# Using QImage load() with filename containing spaces in QT

Tags: c++, qt, qimage

I am using `QImage.load()` to load an image in my program, but it only works when the filename doesn't contain any spaces (for exemple: `"/Users/Emile/Dropbox/crookedStall cover.jpg"`). As I want the user to be able to select any image from their computer, this is a bit of an issue.

The filename of the selected image is returned by a function is stored in a QString. I have tried using `QString.replace()` to escape the spaces with a backslash but that didn't seem to work. Obviously, simply removing the spaces doesn't work either.

I've looked around a bit and didn't find any working solutions.
How can I load an image with a filename that contains spaces? Thanks!

Comment: Qt normally handles spaces correctly.  You might need to surround it in quotes.  Also try using the `QFileDialog::openFile()` for getting the path to the file.

Comment: I'm currently using `QFileDialog::getOpenFileName()` to let the user select the image on their computer and get the filepath. Is that what you meant @phyatt ?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the typo.  I've had that function work for me with spaces in the filename in Windows and Mac without a problem.  What is the return value from `QImage.load`?  You could also try loading with `QImageReader reader("image.png");
// reader.format() == "png"`

Comment: @phyatt `QImage.load()` returns `false`. I just tried reading with `QImageReader.read()` and it failed, with the following error: `Unable to read image data`

Comment: @phyatt Well, apparently it's just the images I was working with. I renamed some other images and the spaces aren't the issue: the images themselves probably were...

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out.  I've had that problem with a gif file before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine for me:

This is just using QFileDialog::getOpenFileNames to locate the files

```
QString filter = QString("Supported Files (*.shp *.kml *.jpg *.png );;All files (*)");
QStringList fileNames = QFileDialog::getOpenFileNames(this, tr("Select File(s)"), QDir::homePath(), filter);
for(int idx =0; idx < fileNames.size(); ++idx)
{
    QImage image ;
    bool success = image.load(fileNames.at(i));
    qDebug() << "File loaded succesfully " << success ;
}
```